# Brightcove Responsive Sizing for Video Players

Tags: html, css, brightcove

I just working on Brightcove Responsive but i am not sure why Brightcove video not resize when I using viewport below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

If i don't use viewport so when I rotate in mobile is working well.

Here my css code

```
<style type="text/css">
        .containing-block {
          width: 100%;
        }
        .outer-container {
          position: relative;
          height: 0;
          padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        }
        .BrightcoveExperience {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
```

And Brightcove code

```
<div class="containing-block">
        <div class="outer-container">

            <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->

            <div style="display:none">

            </div>

            <!--
            By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C 
            found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. 
            -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="//sadmin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

                <object id="myExperience1754276206001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
                  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
                  <param name="width" value="480" />
                  <param name="height" value="270" />
                  <param name="playerID" value="1753810340001" />
                  <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABmA9XpXk~,-Kp7jNgisrdihurn3hYnYJWo8k_gM6uF" />
                  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
                  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
                  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

                  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="1754276206001" />
                </object>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for help me

Comment: I work in Brightcove daily, and can say that unfortunately, they have been weighed and found severely wanting when it comes to responsive player design. I'm assuming you've first checked out the documentation for this: [Brightcove responsive doc](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/responsive-sizing.html) and [iOS viewport they link to](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)